# How to Set default value in 1:m relation, foreign key to user_auth_model in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

I want to set Default value in my table, which must be the primary key of the admin of user_auth_model , But its showing me this error

```
class department(models.Model):
dept_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
adid = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False, default='admin')
def __str__(self):
    return self.dept_name
```

Here is the Error when i save it

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a callable and let that callable link it to the `admin`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def default_admin_user():
    if hasattr(default_user, 'admin'):
        return default_user.admin
    else:
        default_user.admin = result = get_user_model().objects.get(username='admin')
        return result

class department(models.Model):
    # …
    adid = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        default=default_admin_user
    )
```